# ModuleNotFoundError when using Vue chartjs and Vue grid layout

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to use the [Vue chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs) library in my Vue.js project, but I keep encountering the following error:

```js
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/var/www/html/custom/plugins/ShopwareWidgets/src/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist'
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const { join, resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@chartjs': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'chart.js')
                ),
                'vue': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue')
                ),
                '@chartjsvue': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-chartjs')
                )
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        compact: true,
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
}
```

And this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "administration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "mode=production webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "missionlog": "^1.8.8",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

I faced the same issue while trying to use the [Vue grid layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-grid-layout) library as well.

Could someone please help me understand how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why `vue` can't be resolved in your case, as it is a dependency of the administration and you shouldn't have to add it as a dependency in your plugin. For what it's worth you could point an alias to the directory within  `node_modules` of the administration.

```js
'vue': resolve(
    join(process.env.PATH.split(':').at(0), '..', 'vue')
)
```

Comment: `TypeError: process.env.PATH.split(...).at is not a function` Do I have to import somethin else? or how can I fix this error?

Comment: You version of `node` seems to be significantly outdated. That would explain some of the other issues you're having. Update to `v18`.

Comment: Please tell me how I can Update the node version from the Dockware 6.4.20.2 container. I have tried to update the container now for some hours and I either get a GLIBC_2.28 error or the entire container breaks

Comment: Okay, If you are in Dockware, the node version you have should already match Shopware. So if you are still on 6.4.20, Node v16 should be perfectly correct and no upgrade needed.  Are yo eventually building from *outside* of the container ? What does `node -v` show?

Comment: Im using Shopware 6.4.20.2
No, Im building inside of the Container using `bin/build-administration.sh`
my local Node version is `v18.16.1`